# (Vue 3, Nuxt 3) The value from the child component to parent component emits only after adding changes in vs code

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxt3, vueuse

I need to emit the height value from the СhildСomponent into the pages/index component in the puzzleSelectBlockHeight ref. But the problem is that this only happens after I change something in the index.vue component like change text or adding/removing divs. Please tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/test-2-zh3g8r?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.vue%3A11%2C20

https://zh3g8r-3000.csb.app/

Comment: you only call the function `blockHeight` when the component is mounted.  when you change your app and save, the app reloads, and the component remounts.  the code works according to how it is written.  you haven't specifically said what alternative behavior you want, or why the current behavior is wrong, so it's not clear how you would want this "fixed".

Comment: I want to emit value from СhildСomponent to parent component pages/index.vue immeditially on the first mount of the app, not when it remounts.

Comment: It does emit on initial mount.  the onMounted code runs _every_ time the component is mounted. If it didn't mount, you wouldn't see it on the screen.  Have you tried console.logging the value of `height.value` inside the `blockheight` function?  Maybe it's just not emitting the value you expect... If it doesn't log anything on initial mount, then you'd be correct, but that verification is important.

Comment: In console height.value is 0 but in template {{ height }} shows correct value. Maybe you can advice how to emit real height value of div with ref="PuzzleSelectEl" to parentComponent  on first app mount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watchers) instead of the onMounted hook. It will be able to emit the new height any time it changes. I'd also suggest emitting the inner ref value rather than the ref itself, since reactivity across components won't work. The watcher will still make sure the newest height value is always emitted.

**ChildComponent.vue**

```js
function blockHeight() {
  emit('block-height', height.value)
  console.log('height', height.value)
}

watch(height, () => {
    blockHeight()
  },
  { immediate: true }
)
```

Comment: Yes, now it's working as i expected! Thanks) But i see how block with class="parent-block" change his initial height to div height with text, maybe you know how to make this block height with class="parent-block" render before page mounted without this "jump"?